# Disallow specific chars using regex for Dropbox

Tags: c#, regex

These are the chars I must disallow:

```
\ / : ? * < > " |
```

heres what I have so far:

```
Regex r = new Regex("(?:[^a-z0-9 ]|(?<=['\"])s)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);

string cleanedFileName = r.Replace(file.FileName, String.Empty);
```

But from what I understand that disallows ALL special chars.

Comment: Do you need a regex? You can simply chain `.Replace()` for all characters.

Comment: I don't know, but I bet it's micro-optimisation. It sure is easier to understand for yourself and colleagues/future maintainers.

Comment: Why do you want to disallow them?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Those seem to be the characters that are disallowed by Windows for a file name.

Comment: Because filename. See dropbox. http://i.imgur.com/1zwvpE0.png

Comment: Great, I updated the question to be more specific in case someone else wants to do what you are doing.

Comment: Why did you say "For Dropbox"? Id say I want the functionality LIKE Dropbox, or LIKE the Windows file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to sanitize a filename, if so try this:

```
private static string MakeValidFileName( string name )
{
   string invalidChars = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape( new string( System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() ) );
   string invalidRegStr = string.Format( @"([{0}]*\.+$)|([{0}]+)", invalidChars );

   return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace( name, invalidRegStr, "_" );
}
```